# В выводе расшифрованной строки присутствуют некорректные символы

Tags: c++, строки, xor

сегодня я решил попробовать написать шифрование строк и у меня даже получилось. Однако в выводе расшифрованной строки присутствуют лишние символы. Первый символ выходной строки будет заменен на букву "o", а к концу строки будет добавлен юникод.
Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class C_CryptString
{
protected:
  void Encrypt( std::string m_aString )
  {
    for ( int m_iCharPtr = 0; m_iCharPtr < ( int )( m_strSize ^ m_XorKey1 ); ++m_iCharPtr )
    {
      char m_cTemp = m_aString[ m_iCharPtr ];

      m_cTemp ^= m_XorKey1;
      m_cTemp ^= m_XorKey2;

      this->m_aCharArray[ m_iCharPtr ] = m_cTemp;
    }
  }

  void Decrypt( std::string& m_aOutput)
  {
    for ( int m_iCharPosition = 0; m_iCharPosition < ( int )( m_strSize ^ m_XorKey1 ); m_iCharPosition++ )
    {
      char m_cTemp = m_aCharArray[ m_iCharPosition ];
      
      m_cTemp ^= m_XorKey2;
      m_cTemp ^= m_XorKey1;

      m_aOutput.data( )[ m_iCharPosition ] = m_cTemp;
    }
  }
public:
  C_CryptString( std::string m_StringToCrypt )
  {
    this->m_XorKey1 = rand( ) ^ sizeof( m_StringToCrypt.data( ));
    this->m_XorKey2 = rand( ) ^ m_StringToCrypt.length( );
    this->m_strSize = m_StringToCrypt.length( ) ^ this->m_XorKey1;

    Encrypt( m_StringToCrypt );
  }

  void GetDecryptedArray( std::string& m_aOutput )
  {
    Decrypt( m_aOutput );
  }

  char* GetEncryptedArray( )
  {
    return this->m_aCharArray;
  }
private:
  char* m_aCharArray;
  int m_strSize;
  uint32_t m_XorKey1, m_XorKey2;
};

int main( ) 
{
  std::string m_EncryptedData = "";
  std::cout << "Enter string: ";
  std::cin >> m_EncryptedData;

  auto m_String = C_CryptString( m_EncryptedData );
  std::string m_aString = "";
  m_String.GetDecryptedArray( m_aString );
  std::cout << m_aString.data( );
}
```

Вывод программы при вводе 123: o23�

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я забыл выделить память для массива m_aCharArray.
Решение: char m_aCharArray[ размер ]